# Camel SQL Insert From Select

Tags: apache-camel, insert-select, camel-sql

I am using `camel spring dsl` to insert data into the database.

This is the code I am using:

```
camel:to uri=
   "sql:INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE(COL1,COL2) SELECT A.COL1,B.COL2 FROM A,B WHERE SOME_CONDITION"?dataSource="SOME_DataSource"
```

I am not getting any errors, but the data is not being inserted into the database table.
Any idea on why this is happening and what I can do to solve this behavior?

Comment: Which database you are using, if you are using oracle. It might check for commit statement.

Comment: Or there is no data matching the where clause.